# how to stop/terminate the step in execution listeners in spring batch?

Tags: spring-batch, terminate

I had file name validation in step execution listener . If the file name is not valid i want to terminate/stop the step from proceeding  into reader . how to achieve this in sprig batch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The listener is the wrong place to do data validation. use a processor and throw an appropriate exception if you have to validate single data items.

Use a tasklet step prior to a processing step if you want to validate more "general" aspects like the filename or the presence of a file or any other condition that is not part of single item.

Answer (score 2):

Hansjoerg's answer is a valid point. Still as for how to achieve what you're trying to do, here's an example :

```
@Override
public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    return ExitStatus.FAILED;
}
```

This will return an ExitStatus `FAILED` that you can use on your `<next on="" />` tag to prevent from going into the reader.

Comment: Thanks everyone . i moved validation from Listeners to Tasklet as suggested .

Answer (score 0):

The best choice to solve your problem is to use a [JobExecutionDecider](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/job/flow/JobExecutionDecider.html) where you perform filename validation and stop job or move to next step