# Spring Batch stop job execution from external class

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have an existing spring batch project that have multiple steps. I want to modify a step so I can stop the job : `jobExecution.getStatus() == STOPPED`.

My step :

```java
@Autowired
public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
@Autowired
private StepReader reader;
@Autowired
private StepProcessor processor;
@Autowired
private StepWriter writer;
@Autowired
public GenericListener listener;
@Bean
@JobScope
@Qualifier("mystep")
public Step MyStep() throws ReaderException {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("mystep")
            .reader(reader.read())
            .listener(listener)
            .processor(processor)
            .writer(writer)
            .build();
}
```

`GenericListener` implements `ItemReadListener, ItemProcessListener, ItemWriteListener` and overrides before and after methods that basically write log.

The focus here is on the `StepReader` class and its `read()` method that returns a `FlatFileItemReader` :

```java
@Component
public class StepReader {
    public static final String DELIMITER = "|";
    @Autowired
    private ClassToAccessProperties classToAccessProperties;
    private Logger log = Logger.create(StepReader.class);
    @Autowired
    private FlatFileItemReaderFactory<MyObject> flatFileItemReaderFactory;

    public ItemReader<MyObject> read() throws ReaderException {
        try {
            String csv = classToAccessProperties.getInputCsv();
            FlatFileItemReader<MyObject> reader = flatFileItemReaderFactory.create(csv, getLineMapper());
            return reader;
        } catch (ReaderException | EmptyInputfileException | IOException e) {
            throw new ReaderException(e);
        } catch (NoInputFileException e) {
            log.info("Oh no !! No input file");
            // Here I want to stop the job
            return null;
        }
    }
    private LineMapper<MyObject> getLineMapper () {
        DefaultLineMapper<MyObject> mapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        DelimitedLineTokenizer delimitedLineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        delimitedLineTokenizer.setDelimiter(DELIMITER);
        mapper.setLineTokenizer(delimitedLineTokenizer);
        mapper.setFieldSetMapper(new MyObjectFieldSetMapper());
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

I tried to implement `StepExecutionListener` in `StepReader` but with no luck, I think because the `reader` method in `StepBuilderFactory` is expecting an `ItemReader` from the `reader.read()` method and it doesn't care about the rest of the class.

I'm looking for ideas or solution to be able to stop the entire job (not fail it) when `NoInputFileException` is catched.

Comment: here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34005152/how-to-stop-terminate-the-step-in-execution-listeners-in-spring-batch . Luca Basso Ricci comment should work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm looking for ideas or solution to be able to stop the entire job (not fail it) when NoInputFileException is catched.

This is a common pattern and is described in details in the [Handling Step Completion When No Input is Found](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#handlingStepCompletionWhenNoInputIsFound) section of the reference documentation. The example in that section shows how to fail a job when no input file is found, but since you want to stop the job instead of failing it, you can use `StepExecution#setTerminateOnly();` in the listener and your job will end with status `STOPPED`. In your example, you would add that listener to the `MyStep` step.

However, I would suggest to add a pre-validation step and stop the job if there is no file. Here is a quick example:

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJob {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    @Bean
    public Step fileValidationStep() {
        return steps.get("fileValidationStep")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    // TODO add code to check if the file exists
                    System.out.println("file not found");
                    chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().setTerminateOnly();
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step fileProcessingStep() {
        return steps.get("fileProcessingStep")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("processing file");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobs.get("job")
                .start(fileValidationStep())
                .next(fileProcessingStep())
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyJob.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
        System.out.println("Job status: " + jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());
    }

}
```

The example prints:

```
file not found
Job status: STOPPED
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Although this is not the solution I was hoping for, because `MyStep` is by design responsible for validation and reading the input file but your solution helps me to avoid the technical issue with the batch. Thank you

Comment: `MyStep is by design responsible for validation and reading the input file`: [So much complexity in software comes from trying to make one thing do two things](https://twitter.com/codewisdom/status/1006219510741983232). This comment is constructive, I'm just trying to help kindly without questioning your design. But I really recommend to make each step do one thing (and do it well).

Comment: I completely agree with you, but this it's an old existing project and I'm trying to minimize maintaining costs, thus not touching existing design. However I adapted your solution and it works fine for now. Thank you

Comment: How the same can be done in chunk oriented step?