# How to cancel a job

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I would like to have the option to cancel a job during ItemReader beforeStep

This is part of the ItemReader implementation:

```
@Component
public class CustomerDataItemReader implements ItemReader<CustomerDataDto>, StepExecutionListener {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomerDataItemReader.class);
private ItemReader<CustomerDataDto> delegate;
 ...


@Override
public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {

    List<String> list = repository.findAllMacAddress();
    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
        
        String inParams = String.join(",", list.stream().map(macAddress -> "'" + macAddress + "'").collect(Collectors.toList()));

        Map<String, CustomerDataDto> customerDataMap = new HashMap<>();
        logger.info("*****  before stop");
        //stepExecution.getJobExecution().stop();
        stepExecution.getJobExecution().setExitStatus(new ExitStatus("STOPPED", "Invalid"));
        logger.info("*****  after stop");
```

I have tried several API’s but none of them working for me.

Any idea how can I cancel the job ?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to stop/terminate the step in execution listeners in spring batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34005152/how-to-stop-terminate-the-step-in-execution-listeners-in-spring-batch)

Comment: Not exactly. During the "beforeStep" I am collecting data from several endpoints. There is a possibility that one endpoint will failed so I want catch the exception and cancel the job

Comment: I have a workaround. I moved the stepExecution.getJobExecution().stop() to a try and catch. That's works for me.

Comment: JobExecution#stop is deprecated for removal: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1605, so I don't recommend using it. You can send a stop signal to the surrounding job by calling `StepExecution#setTerminateOnly` where appropriate.